# Jquery | Adding Events Date Picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How do I highlight or change the style of a date that has an event?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this a while ago and found that it was easier to use a [different datepicker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/) and style it to act/look like jquery ui datepicker than make the datepicker take in data.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the "Theming" tab in http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/, it'll show you all the classes that you can style in CSS to get whatcha want :-) but i think its ui-state-highlight class

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for code to add event and change theme, I hope this helps you:

```
$("div").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var result = [true, '', null];
        var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
            return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
        });

        if (matching.length) {
            result = [true, 'highlight', null];
        }
        return result;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var date,
            selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
            i = 0,
            event = null;

        while (i < events.length && !event) {
            date = events[i].Date;

            if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                event = events[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (event) {
            alert(event.Title);
        }
    }
});​
```

[Calendar JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/1151/) (retrieved from [jQuery UI Datepicker : how to add clickable events on particular dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578259/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-to-add-clickable-events-on-particular-dates))