# Jquery Datepicker Issues with adding events

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a date picker with a bunch of events that I pull from an rss feed. To make the datepicker I pretty much copy this post: [jQuery UI Datepicker : how to add clickable events on particular dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578259/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-to-add-clickable-events-on-particular-dates)

The issue I am having is that I keep getting the error `event.Date is undefined`. I think this may be because of how I am passing in the dates. The dates come from a collection of strings on page load, that are converted like this:

```
//Convert objects
currentEventInformationString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentStoreEventInformation);
eventDatesString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(storeEventDates);
```

Where currentEventInformationString is a collection of strings containing a title, description, and link and eventDateString is a collection of strings that are dates (I get it from a method that returns `date.ToShortDateString();`

I then add all of my dates to an event array like so (in js):

```
//Adds each event to the date picker
for (var x = 0; x < eventDates.length; x++) {
    //Adds event
    events[x] = [{ Title: currentEvents[x].title.toString(), Date: new Date(eventDates[x].toString()) }];
}
```

I have then tried running a `console.debug(events[x].Title + " " + events[x].Date);` but every time I `undefined undefined`

When I run a debug like this:
 `console.debug(currentEvents[x].title.toString() + " " + eventDates[x].toString());`
I get the correct values so I know that that is not the issue. 
Any suggestions?

Also: I know that the question seems vague so I tried to include as much sample code as I thought was relevant. If you need more let me know. To see how the date picker is made look at the link.

**Edit** Here is how I declare events:

```
//Current event
var events = new Array(eventDates.length);
```

Comment: I added in how I declare events in the edit. And after running `console.log(events)` I found that `events` is getting filled with the correct information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a stray set of brackets. This:

```
events[x] = [{
    Title: currentEvents[x].title.toString(),
    Date: new Date(eventDates[x].toString())
}];
```

Is assigning an array that contains one object literal to `events[x]` but I think you just want to assign an object to `events[x]`:

```
events[x] = {
    Title: currentEvents[x].title.toString(),
    Date: new Date(eventDates[x].toString())
};
```

Comment: Yea that was the issue. I am still getting errors, but at least there different ones now. Thanks for the help