# SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8203'

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function gives me the following error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8203'

All looks good to me,

```
function changeColumnWidth() {
    var w = Math.random() * 200+80;
    $('#menu').css("width", w+"px");
}​
```

can someone spot the error?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a character after the closing curly brace:

I copy-pasted your code in Firefox' console, postfixed with a **undefined method invocation**:

```
'function changeColumnWidth() {\
    var w = Math.random() * 200+80;\
    $(\'#menu\').css("width", w+"px");\
}​'.l(); /* .l() triggers a TypeError, since it's not defined */
```

A TypeError (undefined) shows up, which includes the **parsed (escaped)** code:

`TypeError: "function changeColumnWidth() {    var w = Math.random() * 200+80;    $('#menu').css(\"width\", w+\"px\");}\u200B".l is not a function`.

                                 **^^^^^^ Here's the error.**

Now, the troublemaker is found. To fix it, open your code in a text editor, and remove the invisible character. This character can be detected by walking through all characters using the arrow keys.

Comment: FYI, for long blocks of code, adding a backslash at the end of every line is not funny. That's why I'm using E4X (Firefox-only) to mark a block: `<x><![CDATA[ ... code here ... ]]></x>.toString().l()`

Comment: I have huge javascript that i copied from net how to find those errors ? is there any editor that has find method ?

Answer (score 0):

Open file in Hex Editor (I m using Hex Friend ,http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/)
Remove the character which is showing error
Save file

Comment: Howto find similar tool for windows?