# SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0008' message from the DOCTYPE tag

Tags: html, content-type, doctype, invalid-characters

I am setting up a server and am getting a strange error I have never seen before:

[image]

It is complaining about line 1 in the source, but that is just the `DOCTYPE` tag!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> -->
    ...
```

As you can see I already tried setting the `Content-Type` to be something other than `utf-8`. What is happening here?

Comment: already tried to remove and rewrite the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual cause of the error is not located at line 1. For example, using `eval` also causes errors to be reported at line 1.

Look in your source code for the *BACKSPACE U+0008* character. A method to spot this invisible character is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955242/syntaxerror-invalid-character-u8203/9955265#9955265).

Comment: i'll check it out... looks like it may be caused by my JS compressor, but I can't seem to find the character.

Comment: Thanks for helping me localize the problem. Here is a follow-up question if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354420/rails-asset-pipeline-js-compression-inserting-illegal-characters

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add an comment on line1?

```
<!--empty line for the fun of it-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```