# Rails Asset Pipeline JS Compression Inserting "Illegal Characters"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, compression, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I [just asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353468/syntaxerror-invalid-character-u0008-message-from-the-doctype-tag/10353592#10353592) about an "Illegal Character" in my javascript.

[image]

The answer there led me to find that there is a problem with compressing javascript in the Rails asset pipeline  inserting various Illegal Characters.

The error I was receiving in the post was:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0008'
```

I found that **not using compression caused this to go away completely**... but I want compression! That error was found using the Rails default `uglifer` gem. I thought maybe it was a bug with that particular compression gem so I tried using other compressors as directed on the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-compression). I got very similar, but different errors:

```
Uglifier: SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0008'
Closure:  SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0190'
YUI:      SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0025'
```

I tried looking at the minimized code for these, but because the "Invalid character" is different each time, it is leading me to believe something else is the problem.

[Here](http://cloudfront.giantuser.com/assets/application-37b1a9bb0cb78bb8680fcf0682eb769d.js) is an example compressed JS file. Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

Comment: My hunch tells me that the client is attempting to use the compressed data as if it's the plain data.

Comment: It seems that the file is gzipped twice.

Comment: @Rob, could you explain a bit more? looking at http://cloudfront.giantuser.com/assets/application-37b1a9bb0cb78bb8680fcf0682eb769d.js.gz, It appears to be only gzipped once

Comment: @coneybeare I noticed that "weird" characters were shown in the error console. So, I used `wget http://cloudfront.giantuser.com/assets/application-37b1a9bb0cb78bb8680fcf0682eb769d.js.gz`. [`less <file_name>`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less) showed a set of weird characters, and [`zless <file_name>`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zless) showed the expected code. So, I believe that the response is gzipped twice (un-gzipped once due to the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header).

Comment: Not sure if thats the problem. The page has a single JS file, and other JS works as expected. This means that the JS is having an interpretation problem midway through the file. I find that my Cufon stuff is not working correctly... I will try looking there

Comment: Turns out the problem was with the Cufon js running through any of the JS compressors. Once I switched to Google Web Fonts, then compressed all the remaining files, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you're using `\b` in some of your JavaScript regex, which I believe isn't supported.  Try replacing `\b` with `\u0008`, E.x.

```
string.replace(/\u0008/g, '\\b')
```

Comment: No clue.  I've seen that error before, and the implementation I provided fixes it, however, the result of the character code is obviously varying a lot.  Post back if you figure it out.

Comment: Also, it would make sense that this would occur if you had, say, Apache (or whatever you're using) set to gzip your JS files, and your rewrites would point to the double-compressed file.

Comment: The compressed, combined JS is hosted on amazon and is uncompressed. Checkout the example file I posted in the OP

Comment: *ungzipped That last sentence was confusing

Comment: Turns out the problem was with the Cufon js running through any of the JS compressors. Once I switched to Google Web Fonts, then compressed all the remaining files, it worked just fine.

Comment: Wow, interesting...  Well, that's good to know for the future I suppose.  Thanks for the feedback!