# SyntaxError: illegal character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with with last line of this code. In firebug/console I see

> `SyntaxError: illegal character after });`

When i look in firebug/script i see `});a</script>`. I don't know how to delete it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $('#filput').checkFileType({
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg'],
        success: function() {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});​</script>
```

Comment: This question really doesn't show much research effort at all... The syntax error gives you all the information you need.

Comment: ok, can you replace that code with your exact code please. it would probably help you if you removed all the spaces between the brackets, and did this; `});});</script>`

Comment: I guess the people not realized the real issue here. The `` is probably a missformatting issue from OP. The real issue is about a hidden character. This question - and its answer - was really usefull for SO users as shown by the number of up votes to the answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have indeed an unprintable character before the `</script>` tag. Fortunately jsFiddle shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/byg7b/.

[image]

---

**How to delete it?**

Open the file in your editor, move the cursor before `</script>` and press backspace/delete until you delete `;`. Then add `;` again.

Comment: Invisible error solved.. excellent 1+

Comment: In my case the illegal character was `U+286E` and was caused because the html was piped by powershell e.g. `somescript > output.html` which resulted in `UCS-2 LE BOM` encoding - the fix was to make sure the HTML file was encoded in `UTF-8` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `` in the line:

```
});``
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the two ticks after closing }) of your `checkFileType` function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#filput').checkFileType({
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg'],
        success: function() {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });`` // <-- Here
});​
```