# Error: dailyData[i] is undefined angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with my code. Actually, when i run the application then i get message like `dailyData[i]` is undefined and I am getting the form as 'undefined'.

This is my code:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('starter.isu', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngMaterial']);

    app.controller('isuctrl', function($scope, $http) {
        var service_url = "https:code=isu";
        $http.get(service_url)
        .success(
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            dailyData =data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;

            $scope.dailyForecast = [];

            for(var i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
                $scope.dailyForecast[i] = {
                    callsign: dailyData[i].flight.identification.number.default,
                    statu: dailyData[i].flight.status.generic.status.text,
                    airline: dailyData[i].flight.airline.code.icao,
                    from: dailyData[i].flight.airport.origin.position.region.city,
                    timear: dailyData[i].flight.time.scheduled.arrival,
                    generic: dailyData[i].flight.status.text,
                };
            }
        })
    })
})();
```

Comment: Can you check whether you are getting data from the service.. `console.log(dailyData)`

Comment: Are you getting something in dailyData?

Comment: `Error: dailyData is not defined`

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya no when i use `console.log(dailyData)` get error `Error: dailyData is not defined` and when i remove  `console.log(dailyData)` get error `Error: dailyData[i] is undefined`

Comment: Do this `console.log(data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals)`

Comment: `SyntaxError: illegal character`

Comment: console.log(data) and see whether `data` object has property `result`.. This can also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903395/syntaxerror-illegal-character

Comment: @RaviTeja see image http://b.top4top.net/p_278pq3e1.png

Comment: Your console shows `Error: Access to restricted URI denied`. Have you given proper URL to fetch the data..

Comment: all javascript in root , www/js/...

Comment: i think the problem withe `<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: see image http://e.top4top.net/p_2784ibq1.png

Comment: What does `service_url` hold? does it hold a proper URL to server? Are you getting data from server?

Comment: what you mean i cant see `service_url`

Comment: You have this in question `var service_url = "https:code=isu";`
 `$http.get(service_url)`.. Is this URL correct?

Comment: oh , yes his link get data json from him , i have full url dont worry

Comment: Do `console.log(data)`.  Then expand and find all the properties in this hierarchy `data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data`

Comment: i have result but there no information show , see img for arrival , http://e.top4top.net/p_278vftz1.png . see img for dep http://f.top4top.net/p_278dv882.png

Comment: Did you do `console.log(data)` and expand the logged object and see whether you have the data you want?

Comment: yes do and i all i have . but i dont know whats problem , and everyting okay in code

Comment: Do you have an object `schedule` inside that `arrivals` inside that `data` ?

Comment: see img `http://c.top4top.net/p_278ucpz1.png`

Comment: Try this ..`$scope.dailyData =data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;` and use `$scope` everywhere for accessing `$scope.dailyData[i].flight.identification.number.default`

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: @RaviTeja am sorry , i was busy , i will try now

Comment: @RaviTeja SyntaxError: illegal character

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903395/syntaxerror-illegal-character

Comment: same , thank you very much for help , i really appreciate

Comment: there is an invisible character in your code.. thats the reason you are getting `SyntaxError: illegal character`. If you have `notepad++` you can copy paste you code in there and follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters

Comment: just put `var` in dailydata,  `var dailyData =data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;`