# How show in select a json data on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey im trying to make an cascading select with AJAX.

The problem is the response in format JSON doesn't appear in select list

these is my controller:

```
def fallas
     @falla = Tipos.select("tip_id, tip_titulo").where("tip_id_padre = ?", params[:item])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @falla}
    end

  end
```

The CoffeeScript where i make the AJAX call:

```
jQuery ->

    $('#solicitudes_tip_id_item').change ->

        data = $('#solicitudes_tip_id_item :selected').val()

        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/solicitudes/fallas",
      dataType: 'json'
      data: item:data,
      success:(data) ->
        $('#solicitudes_tip_id_falla').append(data)
      error:(data) ->
        return false
    })
```

and these is the js.erb file when i show the answer (maybe here is the problem)

```
$("#solicitudes_tip_id_falla").empty()
 $("#solicitudes_tip_id_falla").append("<%= render :json(:partial => @falla) %>")
```

The console show me this:

```
[{"tip_id":14,"tip_titulo":"Monitor encendido pero sin imágen"}]
```

but in the select nothing.

How i show the json data or how i can do the cascading select?

Edit:
If i use the function JSON.parse i got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Now, i remove the coffeescript and i made it with Jquery:

```
$("#solicitudes_tip_id_item").change(function(){

        var data = $("#solicitudes_tip_id_item :selected").val();

        $.ajax({
          url: "solicitudes/fallas", 
          data: {item : data}, 
          dataType:'json',
          type:'GET', 


          success: function(resp){
              /*$.each(resp, function(idx, obj) { 
                $('#prueba').append($("<option></option>"‌​).attr("value",obj.t‌​ip_id).text(obj.tip_‌​titulo)); 

              }); 
              */
              var lol= JSON.stringify(resp);
              console.log(lol);
              var lel = JSON.parse(lol)
              console.log(lel);

          } 

        });
```

And in the console log of var lol and lel, show this:
Var lol:

```
[{"tip_id":14,"tip_titulo":"Monitor encendido pero sin imágen"}]
```

Var lel:

```
Array [ Object ]
```

Only need convert that information into a string to parse to the select

Comment: You need to filter it first. Check if params[:item] is not empty by usng params[:item].present? so that you wont get that errors.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I check the query and they work perfect, look: [Started POST "/solicitudes/fallas" for ::1 at 2017-01-13 08:06:30 -0430
Processing by SolicitudesController#fallas as JSON
  Parameters: {"item"=>"12", "success"=>"[object Object]"}
  Tipos Load (0.5ms)  SELECT tip_id, tip_titulo FROM `tipos` WHERE (tip_id_padre = '12')
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)]
. The problem for me is they are returning into an object, ,so i need to make something to transform in text and reflect in  the select

Comment: I think i get it after reading your question. try using this (this code is a javascript not a coffescript I know much coffe so you can convert it) `$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
 $('#solicitudes_tip_id_falla').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",obj.tip_id).text(obj.tip_titulo));
});`

Comment: For the  "success"=>"[object Object]" i need more information about it, i I don't understand it much. sorry.

Comment: the success function is where i receive the answer of the petition in json, the data return is into an object: thiis is how return: [{"tip_id":14,"tip_titulo":"Monitor encendido pero sin imágen"}] but in the javascript appears the [object,object] i'll make the try without coffee and only js if this have success, i'll edit the comment.                                       PD: if you have a code making the cascading select show me to take a look please

Comment: Hey i try the code and show this error: SyntaxError: illegal character

Comment: it would be better if you can show me the whole error or a screenshot of it so that I can see the problem clearly. and alos the [object, object]. Im willing to help.

Comment: it only says "SyntaxError: illegal character" more nothing that's show in the console

Comment: here must be something missing try to check this link it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903395/syntaxerror-illegal-character

Comment: look the code : $.each(resp, function(idx, obj) { 
      $('#prueba').append($("<option></option>"‌​).attr("value",obj.t‌​ip_id).text(obj.tip_‌​titulo)); 
      
     });

Comment: i try with this: $.each(resp, function(t‌​ip_id, tip_‌​titulo){
      alert(t‌​ip_id + ": "+ tip_‌​titulo)
     }); and show the same error, maybe if something in the response

Comment: I think you sould use data instead of resp.

Comment: when checking data in javascript you should also use conslole.log() rather than alert.

Comment: yah but i only use for a test because throws the same error

Comment: did you use data instead of resp? or did you asign resp to data?

Comment: both, i convert the data into a json data, look in the question i posted the console.log take a look