# How to find SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8306' in big javascript code and fix them?

Tags: javascript, text-editor, samsung-smart-tv

I have copied a long javascript code to notepad text editor and saved it as unicode using notepad on windows .But now i get these errors:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u10799'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8306'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u12079'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8306'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u10799'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u11891'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u11891'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u11891'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u12079'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u12079'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u10799'
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u10341'
```

Could you guys point me to a good javascript editor that help me find those error and fix them?since it is huge javascript code it is hard for me to find the error locations. Thanks in advance!

**Note:**I am getting those error on Samsung smart tv simulator log files

Comment: Your browser console will tell you which line those errors are on. If you have the console log the value of those it returns `ၹ9茆ሇ9茆ၹ9ᆉ1ᆉ1ᆉ1ሇ9ሇ9ၹ9ဴ1`

Comment: This is a known question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955242/syntaxerror-invalid-character-u8203 try to download the tool to clean your  file.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Headmax i am developing on windows what tool should i download ? The link you provided is for Mac OS X 10.8(hexfiend) or later!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8203'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955242/syntaxerror-invalid-character-u8203)

Comment: Asking for links for tools is off topic in this forum. I suggest going back to the original script file and save it without putting it in Notepad first. If you have a URL you can create a link to it and right click. Search for "best programming text editor windows" to download a suitable editor.

Comment: @Traktor53 . Thanks a lot for your suggestion.It fixed all the errors i was getting. i right click on the link and saved the pages without copying to notepad and now all the errors gone!

Comment: Fantastic. I would prefer not to change the comment into an answer. Please post a reply saying how you fixed it and accept your own answer - you don't get points, but it indicates the question has been solved. In the meantime, avoid serious use of Notepad :)