# Integrate JQuery plugin to datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datepicker

in my website I have use the jQuery complement called datepicker for representing a calendar. To the datepicker I want to represent date events with some colours dots.

Researching I have found a jQuery plugin that simulates what I need. My problem is that I don't know how to integrate that plugin to my code and to my datepicker.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/event-calendar-evo.html

My datepicker.

```
$('#datepickerSessions').datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                            numberOfMonths: 1,
                            minDate: minDate,//per evitar que mostri mesos passats
                            inline: true,
                            firstDay: 1});
```

Event plugin

```
<div id="evoCalendar"></div>
```

```
myEvents = [
  { name: "New Year", date: "Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)", type: "holiday", everyYear: true },
  { name: "Valentine's Day", date: "Fri Feb 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)", type: "holiday", everyYear: true },
  { name: "Birthday", date: "February/3/2020", type: "birthday" },
  { name: "Author's Birthday", date: "February/15/2020", type: "birthday", everyYear: true },
  { name: "Holiday", date: "February/15/2020", type: "event" },
],
```

```
$('#evoCalendar').evoCalendar({
  calendarEvents: myEvents
});
```

```
$("#evoCalendar").evoCalendar('addCalendarEvent', [
  {
   name: "NEW EVENT",
   date: "February/16/2020",
   type: "birthday",
   everyYear: true
  }
]);
```

Comment: way to use is given on the link you provided. have you downloaded the script/css files and included that under <head> of your html body?

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider yes of courrse! But I want to use the array of events inside $('#datepickerSessions').datepicker(    is it possible.

Comment: check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5581668/2836750
i hope this does what you want. let me know if this works

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider thanks a lot for you answer. I will check it out.

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider that doesn't work to me